# Every Radon measure defines a distribution

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, distribution-theory

I have read that given a Radon measure $\mu$ in  $\mathbb{R}^d$,  the operator $T_{\mu}(\phi)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^d} \phi d \mu$, $\phi \in C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R}^d),$ defines a distribution.
However, when I try to prove this result I find the following difficulties related to integration respect to a Radon measure:

- **If $\phi\in C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R}^d)$, do we have  $\int_{\mathbb{R}^d} \phi d \mu<\infty$?**
- **If $\phi\in C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R}^d)$, can we affirm that  $\int_{\mathbb{R}^d} \phi d \mu\leq  \max{|\phi|}\int_{\mathbb{R}^d} d \mu\ $.**

In general, I would like to know which properties cease to be true when we change Lebesgue measure to an arbitrary Radon measure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: by definition, a Radon measure is finite on compact sets, and the subscript $c$ in $C_c(\mathbb R^d)$ means supported on a compact set.

Comment: Yes, I see it. Thanks. But for the second question I think that it is not enough to obtain the inequality

Comment: If $\phi$ is supported on $K$ and $\max |\phi| = M$, $\phi \le M 1_{K}$ (where $1_K$ is the indicator function of $K$), and so
$\int \phi \; d\mu \le \int M 1_K \; d\mu = M \mu(K) \le M \mu(\mathbb R^d)$

Comment: You're right. It is clear now